# Using Same Customer ID naming in DB with different Clients

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database-design, mean-stack

I am looking for a better Customer ID numbering strategy than the competition has as they add a sequential strategy that no matter what the client ID is the numbering is continuous. So they may have a UCID that is not relevant to location, but only unique to software company. So in theory if I had 1000 locations using our software and each client has 20,000 customer it is obvious the customer ID number could be in the millions.

My thought is take a similar approach as the SSN is as we will have clients using our SaaS in all 50 states. I wanted to take the prefix approach using the number of when the state that the client is in was admitted to the US. So if it was Delaware the prefix would be 01-XXXX and if this was our 37 client in Delaware the ID would be 01-0037 and the very first customer that was entered into this client level DB table would automatically start at 1.

What would be the pros of this idea and what cons could come out of it. I am also hoping that this would allow for easier enterprise reporting

Answer (score 0):

If you have a *single* database server doling out ids, then you can invent whatever scheme you want.

If you "distribute" the number-generating across many servers, then you must come up with some universally unique mechanism, such as UUIDs (which are not  consecutive) or your 2-part mechanism (which is consecutive in the second part).

If you have one sequence per state, keep in mind that California will probably have 100 times as many numbers as the smallest states.  Does this matter.

You should really think about *why* you need a "sequential" numbering strategy at all.

What will you do when there are holes in the numbers?  Such will happen if there are server crashes, etc.  Or when a 'client' vanishes (dies, goes out of business, moves out of state, etc).

Consecutive numbers are useful for Invoices -- so an audit can 'prove' that there are no missing or extra Invoices.  But why for client ids?